# How to get rid of the third party profiler 'SearchArchive'

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, mojave

Last couple of months I am facing the trouble with **SearchArchive** that changes my default search engine and let not edit. I found a profile created as the image in the mac profiles. When I delete that, all get fixed but after few seconds it comes back! Even I Deny it for few times it creates the profile forcefully (as I am seeing it). I am using Mac Mojave 10.14.6.

**Any idea How to stop this!**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This app is Adware and should be removed. Delete the app and then Files related to the SearchArchive adware that needs to be removed are:

```
~/Library/Application Support/com.SearchArchive/SearchArchive
~/Library/Application Support/com.SearchArchiveDaemon/SearchArchive
~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.SearchArchive.plist
~/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.SearchArchiveDaemon.plist
```

Removing these files should stop it from returning. Further info about this adware and how to remove it is [given here](https://www.pcrisk.com/removal-guides/18118-searcharchive-adware-mac).

Comment: I updated to Catalina and now getting ```SearchArchiveDaemon will damage your computer ...This file was downloaded on an unknown date``` ANY IDEA what to do now?

Comment: There is an app called Malwarebytes which will seaech your computer for malware and adware and remove them for you.  I'd get a copy of this and see if it helps.

Comment: https://www.malwarebytes.com